# Adding a column to df that contains count of a value of a different column in the df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df below as:

```
Day 
Morning
Day
Night 
Night
Day
Morning
Day
Day
```

There are other columns in the this df and does not only contain the above column

when I run code below as:

```
df.groupby('day').count()
```

it outputs a df with the count of times each value for day column occurs in the other columns in the df ( its the same count number for each value in the day column)

How can I create a new column that lists those same counts for each value of the Day column?

Expected output:

```
 Day     New_Col
Morning    2
Day        4
Night      2
Night      2
Day        4
Morning    2
Day        4
Day        4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform()` if you want to map back:

```
df['New_Col'] = df.groupby('Day')['Day'].transform('count')
```

Or you can use `map`, and also, `value_counts()`:

```
df['New_Col'] = df['Day'].map(df['Day'].value_counts())
```

Output:

```
       Day  New_Col
0  Morning        2
1      Day        4
2    Night        2
3    Night        2
4      Day        4
5  Morning        2
6      Day        4
7      Day        4
```

Comment: Thank you very much, how come when I tried 

df.groupby('day').value_counts() it didnt work? @Quang Hoang

Comment: @Chris90 not `groupby().value_counts()` just `df['Day'].value_counts()`.

Comment: right sorry, and the best way to add a column is to map that back to the df correct?

Comment: @Chris90 either way is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.groupby.transform('size')`:

```
df['New_Col'] = df.groupby('Day')['Day'].transform('size')
```